# How to click between buttons without any action?

Tags: java, android

I have two columns od buttons, left and right. I have a code that compares when user clicks left button and then right one. It compares button's text. And that works fine. But, I have another issue. I need to freely roam between button on left or right side, to let user clicks on left or right side among buttons of the same side how many times he wants, without any action. Now whenever I click for example two buttons on the left side it takes action, it compares them. I can't have that. Here my onclicklistener and nextQuestion method.

And I set tags in xml file for left and right side buttons, if it's important:

android:tag="l"
android:tag="r"

```
 final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            private Button buttonClicked;
            private int brojacKlikova = 0;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                brojacKlikova++;
                if (brojacKlikova < 6) {

                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

                if (buttonClicked == null) {
                    // first button is clicked
                    buttonClicked = button;
                } else {
                    // second button is clicked
                    if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        counter = counter + 5;
                        score.setText("Poeni: " + counter);
                    } else {
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFCC99));
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    }
                    buttonClicked = null;
                }
                }else{
                brojacKlikova = 0;
                brojacVremena.cancel();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,2200);
         }
            }
     };
```

And nextQuestion:

```
public void nextQuestion() {

        brojacIgara = brojacIgara + 1;


        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{    //Pokusava da otvori db

            mDbHelper.open();  //baza otvorena

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsA = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsB = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();

            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(2), "1")); // this tag should be the same to button that matches
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(3), "1"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(4), "2"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(5), "2"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(6), "3"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(7), "3"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(8), "4"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(9), "4"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(10), "5"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(11), "5"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(12), "6"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(13), "6"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(14), "7"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(15), "7"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(16), "8"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(17), "8"));

            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

            if (brojacIgara < 4){

            pitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).label);
            a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0).tag);
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a1.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a1.setEnabled(true);
            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0).label);
            b1.setTag(labelsB.get(0).tag);
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b1.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b1.setEnabled(true);
            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1).label);
            a2.setTag(labelsA.get(1).tag);
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a2.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a2.setEnabled(true);
            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1).label);
            b2.setTag(labelsB.get(1).tag);
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b2.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            a3.setText(labelsA.get(2).label);
            a3.setTag(labelsA.get(2).tag);
            a3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a3.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a3.setEnabled(true);
            b3.setText(labelsB.get(2).label);
            b3.setTag(labelsB.get(2).tag);
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b3.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b3.setEnabled(true);
            a4.setText(labelsA.get(3).label);
            a4.setTag(labelsA.get(3).tag);
            a4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a4.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a4.setEnabled(true);
            b4.setText(labelsB.get(3).label);
            b4.setTag(labelsB.get(3).tag);
            b4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b4.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b4.setEnabled(true);
            a5.setText(labelsA.get(4).label);
            a5.setTag(labelsA.get(4).tag);
            a5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a5.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a5.setEnabled(true);
            b5.setText(labelsB.get(4).label);
            b5.setTag(labelsB.get(4).tag);
            b5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b5.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b5.setEnabled(true);
            a6.setText(labelsA.get(5).label);
            a6.setTag(labelsA.get(5).tag);
            a6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a6.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a6.setEnabled(true);
            b6.setText(labelsB.get(5).label);
            b6.setTag(labelsB.get(5).tag);
            b6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b6.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b6.setEnabled(true);
            a7.setText(labelsA.get(6).label);
            a7.setTag(labelsA.get(6).tag);
            a7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a7.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a7.setEnabled(true);
            b7.setText(labelsB.get(6).label);
            b7.setTag(labelsB.get(6).tag);
            b7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b7.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b7.setEnabled(true);
            a8.setText(labelsA.get(7).label);
            a8.setTag(labelsA.get(7).tag);
            a8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a8.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a8.setEnabled(true);
            b8.setText(labelsB.get(7).label);
            b8.setTag(labelsB.get(7).tag);
            b8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b8.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b8.setEnabled(true);
            }
}
```

Comment: I'm lost.  You say in your introduction that you want users to click left and right as many times as they want, but if you click left twice, it is taking action.  When I look at your code, you are looking to see if it is the first button clicked and storing it.  Then when the second button is clicked you're comparing it to see if it is the same as the first. If it is, you are setting the score...is that what you mean by "taking action"?

Comment: Yes, first button, then storing, then second button and comparing. But I want only to compare left and right buttons. So, a user needs to click one button on the left and then one on the right. But what if, user clicks one button on the left, but then instead clicking one on the right, he changes his mind about the left one and he now wants to select another one from the left. Now, there's my problem. My code compares the first one on the left and the second one he clicked on the left, and that's not good for my game. I need in that case nothing to happend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set one listener for left buttons and a different one for right buttons. To keep the result you should turn the `buttonClicked` field out of listener to activity where this listener is embedded.
Each listener should set background button to a color you want and reset other buttons background color for every click.

Let me know if it is what you want.

Comment: Can you get back to me about details on this on email?

Answer (score 0):

```
        a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).label);
        a1.setTag(0);
        ...
        b1.setTag(1);
        ...
        a2.setTag(2);
```

and so on.

When you do your check to see if they're different, get the tag and convert to int then use modulo (%) to divide by 2 and see if it is column A or B.

If you need to get the tag, refer back to the labels arrays using the int you just got / 2 as the index.

Comment: No, that's not good for me. Here's a screenshot, maybe it will help. [link](http://i.imgur.com/70LuHjs.jpg) Let's say user clicks on button A4, and instead clicking on some of the B buttons, he again clicks on A2, and again on A7 and now he clicks on some B button, for example B3. I need ONLY THEN to compare text values of buttons A7 and B3. I only need comparation between A and B columns, not A or B buttons between themselves. I want user to freely go between A column and nothing to happend, until he press some of the B buttons. I don't know how to explain better.

Comment: I didn't see what MyStruct was doing and assumed that you had the tag being set to be the column.  So, just check the first letter of the text then.  If they're both A then both are from column A, therefore they must be different -- see my updated answer.

Comment: :) No, actually those letters are just for explaining purpose. I populate those buttons with random terms from sqlite db. For example "connect cities with their countries" or "Songs with singers". But I placed in xml file lines android:tag="l" and android:tag="r" if that helps somehow.

Comment: Ok, then try mapping it like this.  Button A1 will have tag 0.  Button B1 will have tag 1.  Button A2 will have tag 2, Button B2 has tag 3. etc.  Now you have even tags on the left and odd on the right.  If tag % 2 = 0 then it is column A if tag % 2 == 1 then column B.  Furthermore, if it is in column A or B tag / 2 will tell you which label it is.

Comment: I can't actually do that, I need to have these tags I already use, cause that my way of comparing buttons, eg. A1 and B1 tag is 1 and so on. :) I know, this one is tricky.

Comment: Can you take MyStruct and add a button to it so labelsA and B will have buttons too. When you assign the text and tags to the buttons, assign the button to the label. When you get your callback, scan labelA comparing the button object that got pressed to each button in labelA. If it is a match, that buton is in col Aa otherwise it is in B. you still have lots of options, but it will take either a rewite of some of your code or a patch...this is a patch but should get it working